# how to see Spring Batch Step descriptions in STS Bean list

Tags: spring-batch, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I use STS and am writing a Spring-Batch application.  When I click on the xml with all my beans, it opens a panel where I can look at the job configuration.  There are 6 tabs to choose from: Source:NamesSpaces:OverView:batch:batch-graph:beans.

One day out of the blue on the batch tab, I saw the ID of each job step displayed to the right of the Step in the left-side list.  Now, I can't figure out how to see the ID again.  It's gone.

I don't know what I did to make it show, nor what I did to lose it.

It makes working with the steps far easier when you can see the ID.

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I'd ask on the STS forums: http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?32-SpringSource-Tool-Suite

Comment: did you happen to upgrade your STS by any chance?  i can see the step names on the batch tab on STS 2.9.x, but not on STS 3.3.0 - i think an upgrade might've killed it?

Comment: My version of STS is 2.9.2.  I'll go ahead and add this message on the STS forum.  Thank you.